# Android Google-Shopping API force closes while parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, google-api-java-client, google-shopping-api

I'm trying to send a request to the Google-Shopping API with the following static method which I think is working:

```
public static String GET_TITLE(String url) throws JSONException {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // http post
    try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
```

The URL I'm passing is this BTW: https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/country=US&q=shirts&alt=json                    &rankBy=relevancy&key=AIzaSyDRKgGmJrdG6pV6DIg2m-nmIbXydxvpjww

Next I try to parse this response (where I think the problem comes in) in the same method:

```
    try {
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    } catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    JSONObject itemObject = jArray.getJSONObject("items");
    JSONObject productObject = itemObject.getJSONObject("product");

    String attributeGoogleId = productObject.getString("googleId");
    String attributeProviderId = productObject.getString("providerId");
    String attributeTitle = productObject.getString("title");*/
    String attributePrice = productObject.getString("price");
    JSONObject popupObject = productObject.getJSONObject("popup");

        return attributeTitle;
    }
```

This has been so frustrating, I know it should be simple but everywhere I look I just can't quite get it to work, I'm not exactly sure what the error is since I'm testing it on my HTC Desire because my emulator gives an 'invalid command-line parameter' error when starting, but that's a different issue, anyway, thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The first one makes it look like there's a problem with the URL, should I change it and see if it makes a difference?

```
04-01 12:09:05.142: ERROR/log_tag(24968): Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
04-01 12:09:05.142: ERROR/log_tag(24968): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 12:09:05.142: ERROR/log_tag(24968): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-01 12:09:05.142: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(24968): Shutting down VM
04-01 12:09:05.142: WARN/dalvikvm(24968): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {     act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity     {com.spectrum.stock/com.spectrum.stock.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3734)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at com.spectrum.stock.JSONResponse.GET_TITLE(JSONResponse.java:61)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at com.spectrum.stock.CaptureActivity.onActivityResult(CaptureActivity.java:78)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)
04-01 12:09:05.152: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24968): ... 11 more
04-01 12:09:05.162: WARN/ActivityManager(96):    Force finishing activity com.spectrum.stock/.CaptureActivity
```

EDIT: Error log from LogCat after changes made.

```
04-01 15:00:33.912: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): native_access_parm: error (No such file or directory): fd 30, type 1, length 32, status 0
04-01 15:00:34.002: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): num_buffers = 4
04-01 15:00:34.002: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): num_buffers = 8
04-01 15:00:34.082: ERROR/mm-camera 8x vfe(67): vfe_util_updaterollofftbl: sensor doesn't support rolloff correction by VFE
04-01 15:00:35.022: ERROR/mm-camera-af(67): af_algo_preview: FAILED....
04-01 15:00:37.872: ERROR/mm-camera-af(67): af_algo_preview: FAILED....
04-01 15:00:38.052: ERROR/mm-camera 8x-vfe(67): Received VFE Stop ACK!!! ctrlCmd is NULL
04-01 15:00:38.482: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): native_access_parm: error (No such file or directory): fd 30, type 1, length 32, status 0
04-01 15:00:38.542: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): num_buffers = 4
04-01 15:00:38.542: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(67): num_buffers = 8
04-01 15:00:38.602: ERROR/mm-camera 8x vfe(67): vfe_util_updaterollofftbl: sensor doesn't support rolloff correction by VFE
04-01 15:00:39.182: ERROR/mm-camera-af(67): af_algo_preview: FAILED....
04-01 15:00:41.662: ERROR/mm-camera-af(67): af_algo_preview: FAILED....
04-01 15:00:44.742: ERROR/mm-camera-af(67): af_algo_preview: FAILED....
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): catch exception
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'BASE64' as integer
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:433)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:682)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at com.htc.android.mail.server.ImapServer.getTheDisplaySize(ImapServer.java:2810)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at com.htc.android.mail.server.ImapServer.processFetchInfo(ImapServer.java:2694)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at com.htc.android.mail.server.ImapServer.fetchInfo(ImapServer.java:2531)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at com.htc.android.mail.server.ImapServer.refresh(ImapServer.java:1348)
04-01 15:00:47.422: ERROR/ImapServer(351): at com.htc.android.mail.RequestController$MainRequestQueueThread.run(RequestController.java:570)
04-01 15:00:47.622: ERROR/log_tag(26112): Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
04-01 15:00:47.632: ERROR/log_tag(26112): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.spectrum.stock/com.spectrum.stock.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3734)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at com.spectrum.stock.JSONResponse.GET_TITLE(JSONResponse.java:63)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at com.spectrum.stock.CaptureActivity.onActivityResult(CaptureActivity.java:78)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3931)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3730)
04-01 15:00:47.642: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26112):     ... 11 more
04-01 15:00:48.272: ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-01 15:00:48.282: ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-01 15:00:48.282: ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-01 15:00:48.282: ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-01 15:00:48.282: ERROR/JavaBinder(96): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: can you provide the error log and the response

Comment: I've edited my post to include the error log from the LogCat

Comment: In the above the result value is "" since the "Inputstream is" is not being converted to String.

Comment: What is the exact url url you are using to fetch data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968114/android-sending-https-get-request), I think it was only a minor thing as it worked after changing only a few things which stopped the response from being null as the request was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the above the result value is "" since the "Inputstream is" is not being converted to String. to convert it to string use following method and try


    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                is.close();
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError om){
                //Constants.TEXT_NETWORKERROR = Constants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION;
                om.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                //Constants.TEXT_NETWORKERROR = Constants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }//convertStreamToString()


Minor changes in your code to handle NullpointerException

try {
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);  
JSONObject itemObject = jArray.getJSONObject("items");
    JSONObject productObject = itemObject.getJSONObject("product");

    String attributeGoogleId = productObject.getString("googleId");
    String attributeProviderId = productObject.getString("providerId");
    String attributeTitle = productObject.getString("title");*/
    String attributePrice = productObject.getString("price");
    JSONObject popupObject = productObject.getJSONObject("popup");

        return attributeTitle;          
    } catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
return null;
    }


    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, unfortunately the lines "Constants.TEXT_NETWORKERROR = Constants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION" and "Constants.TEXT_NETWORKERROR = Constants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION" give 'cannot be resolved' errors however after commenting them out I get the same result (force close). Also I noticed that the first error in the LogCat is 'Error in http connection' which is in the catch clause for the first try bracket meaning that it is failing right? I was calling your method just after the first catch clause but it seems like the problem comes earlier, was I using it in the wrong place?

Comment: Done! This error popped up again - "Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com"

Comment: Your code is right but you have handle exception in your HTTPpost

Comment: I thought I was already handling it with my catch bracket, what else can I do? Or should I take it out completely? Sorry I don't understand what you mean could you explain it a little more please?

Comment: How should I edit it? Should I take it out and replace it or just remove it entirely?

Comment: Thanks, no longer getting that force close however the log still complains  about an error in the http connection with www.googleapis.com throwing an unknown host exception, does this simply mean I have the wrong URL and I only need to change that or is it my code that is the problem? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, very much, also I just put the URL I'm using into google and it returned the response I was hoping for therefore the problem with the connection must be my code sending a bad request.

Comment: Almost, the try bracket always returns null no matter what - "catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
return null;"