# How to send notifications from an Android Phone to a website?

Tags: php, android, apk

I am currently working on my project like Parental control. I am trying to find a way , that if there is any procedure or way to send a notification from an android phone to a website whenever the android phone sends/receives an SMS and dials/receives a call. On website , a database will be maintained for these notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send a get request or post request to a website.
[Sending POST data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)
[Android - Sending HTTPS Get Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968114/android-sending-https-get-request)

Just some examples. You will probably be looking for a restful api. I haven't read this, but it looks viable:
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to maintain database, based on mobile even. You can create API call, that will send data to database while any activity happened on mobile. That api will store notification on DB.

On web you can create AJAX call that will check in DB, if any new notification come or not, if new record found you can show it on website.

This is what I think the best way to do so...